# How to pass shell script argument in perl module's subroutine

Tags: perl, shell, arguments, subroutine

```
#!/bin/bash
export IPV6=$1
expanded_ipv6_addr=`perl -e 'require "/usr/bin/ipv6_helper.pm"; $expand_ipv6=expand_ipv6_addr($ENV{IPV6});print $expand_ipv6'`
```

I don't want to export the `$IPV6` variable, so I am looking any other way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you write a Perl script `expand_ipv6_addr` that expands addresses given as command line arguments?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with passing it to `perl` via its environment?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the value from @ARGV:

```
expanded_ipv6_addr=$(
  perl -e '
    require "/usr/bin/ipv6_helper.pm"; 
    print expand_ipv6_addr(shift)
  ' "$IPV6"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of exporting $1 into an environment variable you could use it again later and escape the perl code.

The following worked for me with a stubbed out version of /usr/bin/ipv6_helper.pm

```
#!/bin/bash
IPV6=$1
expanded_ipv6_addri=`perl -e "
   require \"/usr/bin/ipv6_helper.pm\";
   \\$expand_ipv6 = expand_ipv6_addr($IPV6);
   print \\$expand_ipv6
"`
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `./expand 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334` gives a number of syntax errors because `expand_ipv6_addr(2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334)` is not valid Perl code.

Comment: You might be tempted to add quotes, that would only be a partial fix because that would allow `./expand '".malicious()."'`. Generating code is an awful idea. Instead, you should use a parameter, the environment (which the OP forbade for unknown reasons), STDIN, etc.